# Excel Chart Axis Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want my axis on my charts to display numbers to the tenth. So instead of 2 or 3, I want the axis to read 2.0 and 3.0. Please help. I have already rummaged through the format setting and am lost.

Comment: I presume you are speaking of a chart. If so, please mention that in the text and add the [charts] tag.

Answer (score 2):

if this is about a chart, then double-click to format the axis, go to the Numbers section, select the format called "Number" and set the desired number of decimal places.

The exact dialog and steps will differ with your Excel version, so if you need more details with screenshots, tell us what version you are using.